# Make an image move elliptically

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to make a picture of an ice skater skating on an speed skating rink. This is my code, but I realised that this only make the skater move circularly and doesn't fit with the picture of the rink.
So how do I make an epileptically movement?

```
x = 700  // center
y = 200   // center
r = 200   // radius
a = 0    // angle (from 0 to Math.PI * 2)

function rotate(a) {

    var px = x + r * Math.cos(a); // <-- that's the maths you need
    var py = y + r * Math.sin(a);

    document.querySelector('#point').style.left = px + "px";
    document.querySelector('#point').style.top = py + "px";  
}


setInterval(function() {
    a = (a + Math.PI / 360) % (Math.PI * 2);
    rotate(a);
}, 5);
</script>
<style>
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

#center {
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    background: black;
}

#imgLoper {
  left: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="center">
    <img src="bane.jpg" id="imgBane">
    </div>
    <div id="point">
    <img src="Lorentzen.png" id="imgLoper"></img>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would try changing the value of r for the two lines `px` and `py`. For example, you have r = 200 for both -- try setting a variable `ry` instead of `r` for the `py` line, and set `ry` at 400.

Comment: That did work, thanks! However, the epilleptical movement is too small for the field. How do I "stretch" the movement on the x-axis so it gets bigger= @TKoL

Comment: change the values of 'r' for x and y, until it does what you want. experiment with changing those values.

Comment: Thanks, @TKoL! This was very helpful!

Comment: you're moving the `DOM` every `5ms` .. try putting 4 or 5 of this in a single page and your browser will crash , please consider using css animation for this, there are plenty of examples out there,

Answer (score 0):

This can get you elliptical movement:

```
var px = Math.cos(a)*w/2 
var py = Math.sin(a)*h/2
```

You may need some adjustments to get it to fit within your rink

```js
w = 700 // ellipse width
h = 200 // ellipse height
ellipseCenter = {
  "x": 340,
  "y": 90
}
a = 0 // angle (from 0 to Math.PI * 2)

function rotate(a) {

  var px = Math.cos(a) * w / 2 + ellipseCenter.x
  var py = Math.sin(a) * h / 2 + ellipseCenter.y
  document.querySelector('#point').style.left = px + "px";
  document.querySelector('#point').style.top = py + "px";
}


setInterval(function() {
  a = (a + Math.PI / 360) % (Math.PI * 2);
  rotate(a);
}, 5);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

#center {
  background: black;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
}

#point {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="point">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, but what are the w and h variables? What values should they have? 
EDIT: Sorry, didn't read through properly! @claytronican

Comment: The width and height of the ellipse (major and minor axes)

Comment: How do I change the center of the ellipse? @claytronican

Comment: I edited my example to show an approach to control the center point of the ellipse

Comment: Aha, so i'll change it to that and then it is just to experiment with the x and y values? @claytronican

Comment: In my example, it's approximately 1/2 the width and height to fit in the "rink" the offset is likely due to the registration point of the div not being center. That could be compensated for as well.